# How to load a javascript file into a WebView in a osx app?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Basically I have a webview and I want to run some javascript on pages that get loaded. The basic loading happens like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.js"]];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL filePath];

NSString *basicLoadScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.write('<script src=\"%@\"></script>')",imageURL];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:basicLoadScript];
```

This was my latest attempt, and I get the error:

> Not allowed to load local resource

Is there a better way to load files? (or at least one that works) Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the content of the file into a string and use then the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` function with that string as an argument.

Letting the WebView directly access the file is probably disallowed for security reasons (but that is just a suspicion, I don't have any proof).

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing.. couldn't post an answer myself due to my low rep. Cheers